# How to have multiple subscribers to Flux that run on different execution contexts / threads

Tags: java, resttemplate, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-websocket

I'm developing a Spring Boot WebFlux application for IoT real time data visualization.

I have a `Flux` which simulates data coming from a device, and I want that upon websocket connection established every single event:

- must be sent over the websocket for real time visualization (using reactive `WebSocketHandler`)
- must be checked against a given condition so to send a notification via HTTP REST call (`RestTemplate`)

From my logs it seems the two subscribers (the websocket handler and the notifier) gets two different flows with completely different values (below the logs).

I also tried a variant chaining the `share` method after the `map` in the `MySource` class, in this case it looks like though I have just one Flux, there is only ONE thread so everything is blocking (I can see the REST call blocks the sending over the websocket).

What happens here? How can I make the two subscribers to be run in different execution contexts (different threads), so completely independent from each other?

Below relevant code snippets and logs.

Thank you all in advance!

**UPDATE:** for the sake of clarity I have to specify that `MyEvent`s have RANDOM-generated values, so I solved one issue thanks to @NikolaB's answer by using the `ConnectableFlux` / `share` which guarantees to have the same `Flux`, but I still want to have separate execution contexts for the two subscribers.

```
public class MyWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

   @Autowired
   public MySource mySource;

   @Autowired
   public Notifier notifier;

   public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
            Flux<MyEvent> events = mySource.events();
            events.subscribe(event -> notifier.sendNotification(event));
            return webSocketSession.send(events.map(this::toJson).map(webSocketSession::textMessage));
   }

   private String toJson(MyEvent event) {
       log.info("websocket toJson " + event.getValue());
       ...
   }
}
```

```
public class MySource {
   public Flux<MyEvent> events() {
      return Flux.interval(...).map(i -> new MyEvent(*Random Generate Value*);
   }
}
```

```
public class Notifier {

   public void sendNotification (MyEvent event) {
      log.info("notifier sendNotification " + event.getValue());
      if (condition met)
         restTemplate.exchange(...)
   }
}
```

```
2019-11-19 11:58:55.375 INFO [     parallel-3] i.a.m.websocket.MyWebSocketHandler  : websocket toJson 4.09
2019-11-19 11:58:55.375 INFO [     parallel-1] i.a.m.notifier.Notifier : notifier sendNotification 4.86
2019-11-19 11:58:57.366 INFO [     parallel-1] i.a.m.notifier.Notifier : notifier sendNotification 4.24
2019-11-19 11:58:57.374 INFO [     parallel-3] i.a.m.websocket.MyWebSocketHandler  : websocket toJson 4.11
2019-11-19 11:58:59.365 INFO [     parallel-1] i.a.m.notifier.Notifier : notifier sendNotification 4.61
2019-11-19 11:58:59.374 INFO [     parallel-3] i.a.m.websocket.MyWebSocketHandler  : websocket toJson 4.03
2019-11-19 11:59:01.365 INFO [     parallel-1] i.a.m.notifier.Notifier : notifier sendNotification 4.88
2019-11-19 11:59:01.375 INFO [     parallel-3] i.a.m.websocket.MyWebSocketHandler  : websocket toJson 4.29
2019-11-19 11:59:03.364 INFO [     parallel-1] i.a.m.notifier.Notifier : notifier sendNotification 4.37
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are couple of issues here, first `RestTemplate` is synchronous/blocking HTTP client so you should use `WebClient` which is reactive, also to create `ConnectableFlux` (`Flux` which can have multiple subscribers) you need to share it before `map` operator and create new `Flux`-es which are created from connected one.

Example:

```
Flux<MyEvent> connectedFlux = mySource.events().share();
Flux.from(connectedFlux).subscribe(event -> notifier.sendNotification(event));
return webSocketSession.send(Flux.from(connectedFlux).map(this::toJson).map(webSocketSession::textMessage));
```

Also `sendNotification` method should return `Mono<Void>` since reactive methods should always return `Mono` or `Flux`types.

To initiate independent executions you could `Zip` those two `Mono`s.

**Edit**

First of all as mentioned above use `WebClient` for outgoing HTTP calls which is reactive HTTP client and rework the `Notifier` class:

```
public class Notifier {

   public Mono<Void> sendNotification (MyEvent event) {
      log.info("notifier sendNotification " + event.getValue());
      return Mono.just(event)
                 .filter(e -> /* your condition */)
                 .flatMap(e -> WebClient.builder().baseUrl("XXX")...)
                 .then();
   }

}
```

Now take a look if execution context is different.

Comment: I managed to use `ConnectableFlux` / `share` so now the single Flux source is guaranteed, but the problem is that `sendNotification` is called by the same thread that executes the websocket stuff. What I want to achieve is a separation of execution contexts for subscribers. Is it possible? I feel I have to add `subscribeOn` somewhere but I'm not sure...

Comment: I've edited the body of my question to better clarify this.

Comment: @vortex.alex Yes it's possible, but not with `subscribeOn` or `publishOn` because WebClient and reactive WebSockets each have their own non-blocking threads and your `subscribeOn` or `publishOn` would be overridden by their internal execution definition. Added more code to my answer.

Comment: I tried but either I don't get any response from the `WebClient` or I end up to put a `block` after `exchange` or `retrieve` but it doesn't work 'cause I have the following error: `block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-2`.  Should I explicitly put a subscription on the `WebClient` to fire the request (e.g. using `block`)? Or maybe the `Mono` returned by `exchange` has to be returned back by the `sendNotification` method, but then what to do there? Is there something that has to do with  `zip` method you mentioned?

Comment: Absolutely you have to call `subscribe` to initiate reactive execution so `notifier.sendNotification(event).subscribe()` will initiate execution. You don't have to call `subscribe` on reactive method/operator chains returned in `Controller`s because Spring implicitly calls it, but for all other executions you need to explicitly call it. The `zipWith` operator could be used for independent reactive executions when you need results of multiple independent reactive method executions downstream for further manipulations.

Comment: Ok now it works! with the `subscribe` I'm able to fire the http request and i finally see the non-blocking behavior that I wanted. However, I noticed a slightly different behavior on execution contexts, as opposed to what you said, 
for example reactive websockets inherit and are run on the thread pool set upstream by the `Flux.interval` I used in `MySource` class
(which is `parallel` scheduler, see [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#interval-java.time.Duration-)). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note also that you are using "cold" flux to simulate events (Flux.interval(...)). In reality, there will be some Sink I think. Try to play with this code:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class ReactiveController {
    record SomeDTO(String name, String address) {
    }

    private final Sinks.Many<SomeDTO> eventSink = Sinks.many().replay().latest();

    @RequestMapping(path = "/sse", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ServerSentEvent<SomeDTO>> sse() {
        final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
        return eventSink.asFlux()
                .map(e -> ServerSentEvent.builder(e)
                        .id(counter.incrementAndGet() + "")
                        //.event(e.getClass().getName())
                        .build());
    }

    // note, when you want this to work in production, ensure, that http request is not being cached on its way, using POST method for example.
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(path = "/sendSomething", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String sendSomething() {
        this.eventSink.emitNext(
                new SomeDTO("name", "address"),
                (signalType, emitResult) -> {
                    log.warn("Some event is being not send to all subscribers. It will vanish...");
                    // returning false, to not retry emitting given data again.
                    return false;
                }
        );
        return "Have a look at /sse endpoint (using \"curl http://localhost/sse\" for example), to see events in realtime.";
    }
}
```